# Optimization of a colour graph

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

Formulate as a discrete optimization problem:

Label each node of the graph with a different non negative integer number, in such a way that the numbers of the nodes of each path composed of the same color edges add the same and the total sum be minimum.

I have all the restrictions except that one that makes the variables take different values. I don't know how to do because it must be a linear equation.

[image]

Comment: A better way to write your Question would emphasize what you have tried and where you encountered difficulty.  Too often a Reader will mistakenly guess at what sort of help is needed, wasting their time and yours.  Please review [ask].

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: Take an integer $M \ge 9$ such that you think there is an optimal solution with largest number at most $M$.
Define boolean variables $x(i,j)$, where $x(i,j) $ is to be $1$ if node $i$ is assigned integer $j$, otherwise $0$.  The constraint $\sum_{j=0}^{M} x(i,j) = 1$
implies that each node $i$ is assigned one integer.  The constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{10} x(i,j) \le 1$ implies that each integer is assigned to at most 
one node.

Note that any solution with largest  number $ M$ will have sum at least 
$0+\ldots+8+M = M + 36$. If your first guess at $M$ allows a solution with sum $S$, and $S > M + 36$, then try again with $M = S - 37$.

Comment: But then j just can be an integer between 1 and 10. How do you know it won't be a variable whose value is 30?

Comment: Good point.  I'll edit.